# Change of variables in Power series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

Hello StackExchange community,

this is probably a dumb question, but suppose you have a function that have the following power series

$f= \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} f_i r^i$.

where $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f_i$ are real constant coefficients. Is it possible to obtain asymptotic expansion of the following form

$f = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \hat{f}_i r^{c\,i}$

where $c$ is just a constant?

*Backstory*: I'm solving Dirichlet boundary condition for Laplace equation in 2 dimensions. Asymptotic expansion of the solution in polar coordinates is known in this case

$u = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} r^{\lambda_j} \left(a_j\,
\cos({\lambda_j \theta}) + b_j \sin 
(\lambda_j \theta)\right), \quad \lambda_j = j \frac{\pi}{\Theta}$

with $\Theta$ being angle between boundaries. Now I want to find coefficients $a_j$, $b_j$ by applying to boundary conditions, say $f\vert_{\theta_1}, g\vert_{\theta_2}$ in the following way

$r^{\lambda_j}  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\lambda_j\theta_1) & \sin(\lambda_j\theta_1) \\
  \cos(\lambda_j\theta_2) & \sin(\lambda_j\theta_2) \\
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a_j \\
  b_j
 \end{bmatrix}  =
r^{\lambda_j}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 f_j \\
 g_j
 \end{bmatrix}$.

That is my motivation. If expansions for boundary conditions are not given in $\lambda_j$ I cannot do this. Or can I do something similar?

Comment: of course you have to explain what are $f,f_i,r^i$ in your 1st formula... real, complex, $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ functions.. ?

Comment: did you mean $f(r,\theta) = \sum_i b_i(\theta) r^i$ with $r, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to StackExchange. in my 1st formula $f(r):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f_i$ are constant coefficients $f_i \in \mathbb{R}$. There is no $\theta$ involved in first formula, because this is boundary condition prescribed along the straight edge coming out of origin. And there are two Dirichlet boundary conditions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: there is an "edit" button...

Comment: and I don't get your second formula, what you'd expect...

Comment: did you mean that $r \in [0,+\infty[$, i.e. the power series converges for every $r$, and asking for an asymptotic expansion $f(r) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i r^i \sim \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i d^r$ as $r \to +\infty$ ?

Comment: you are boring... in your 1st formula write $f(r) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i r^i $